# config_vars.mk missing in default xampp-linux installation

Tags: python, apache, xampp, mod-wsgi

I extracted the xampp package xampp-linux-1.6.7 on a Ubuntu 8.10 system and followed the instuctions from mod_wsgi documentation. I get the error below:

```
ravi@Ibex:~/mod_wsgi-2.3$ ./configure  --with-apxs=/opt/lampp/bin/apxs 
checking Apache version... cannot open /opt/lampp/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /opt/lampp/bin/apxs line 218.
cannot open /opt/lampp/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /opt/lampp/bin/apxs line 218.
./configure: line 1696: /: is a directory

checking for python... /usr/bin/python
cannot open /opt/lampp/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /opt/lampp/bin/apxs line 218.
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: Makefile.in
```

I could not google for instructions on getting mod_wsgi running on xampp. Please help.

Solution:
The solution for this is buried in the comments. Thanks to [Martin v. Löwis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33006/martin-v-l246wis) I was able to solve this. When apxs throws and error complaining about missing config_vars.mk it means that the build directory of Apache is missing. Fox xampp users the solution is to download xampp-dev as well and extract that to the same path.

Comment: Do you have a directory /opt/lampp/bin? What files does it contain?

Comment: I do have that directory and it contains apxs (and mysql and other executables, total 262 files). I tried running apxs alone, and got the same error saying "cannot open /opt/lampp/build/config_vars.mk" I don't have the /opt/lampp/build director though. How do I get this?

Comment: config_vars is generated when Apache is built.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I have to get the Development package as well for xampp. I installed the default one. Will post back here after trying it. Thanks again.

Comment: Seems this question was solved through the comments. Anyway for me to mark this as answered?

Comment: There is a way. Just put the answer below and mark your own answer as correct. In case you want to give someone else some rep I can answer this. :D. By the way this was helpful.

Comment: Since nobody added the solutuion as an answer, I did, so we can get rid of this question from the Unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When apxs throws and error complaining about missing config_vars.mk it means that the build directory of Apache is missing. Fox xampp users the solution is to download xampp-dev as well and extract that to the same path.